# is it correct way to create a thread safe queue using pthreads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I recently started learning multithreading, so I still don't understand some things. I tried to write a thread-safe queue, but I doubt if I did everything right. Since I do not quite notice my mistakes, I would be glad if you pointed them out to me. Thank you for your responses!
Also, I'm not sure if I am using a conditional variable correctly in this code.

```
template<class T>
class SafeQueue {
private:
    std:: queue<T> _data;
    pthread_mutex_t _mutex;
    pthread_cond_t _condition;
public:
    SafeQueue();
    ~SafeQueue();
    void push(const T &x);
    T front();
    T back();
    void pop();
    int size();
    bool empty();
};

template<class T>
SafeQueue<T>::SafeQueue(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&_condition, NULL);
}

template<class T>
SafeQueue<T>::~SafeQueue(){
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&_mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&_condition);
}

template<class T>
void SafeQueue<T>::push(const T &x){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    _data.push(x);
    pthread_cond_signal(&_condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
}

template<class T>
T SafeQueue<T>::front(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    if(_data.empty() && _data.size() == 0){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
        throw SafeQueueException("Queue is empty");
    }
    if(_data.empty()){
        pthread_cond_wait(&_condition, &_mutex);
    }
    T temp = _data.front();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    return temp;
}

template<class T>
T SafeQueue<T>::back(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    if(_data.empty() && _data.size() == 0){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
        throw SafeQueueException("Queue is empty");
    }
    if(_data.empty()){
        pthread_cond_wait(&_condition, &_mutex);
    }
    T temp = _data.back();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    return temp;
}

template<class T>
void SafeQueue<T>::pop(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    if(_data.empty() && _data.size() == 0){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
        throw SafeQueueException("Queue is empty");
    }
    if(_data.empty()){
        pthread_cond_wait(&_condition, &_mutex);
    }
    _data.pop();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
}

template<class T>
int SafeQueue<T>::size(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    int temp = _data.size();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    return temp;
}

template<class T>
bool SafeQueue<T>::empty(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    bool temp = _data.empty();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: for reviews of working code there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

some points in code i did not understand very well why you put `_data.empty() && _data.size() == 0` something like this? when you can use only one of them. and also there is no need lock for size and empty method because they are only reading variable and returned them they do not modify anything.

BTW.

it is true that some people think if they put mutex in start and end operation is some data structure(in your case queue) then they think it's thread safe now but it's NOT TRUE.

for example imagine your queue has one element.

q = 1

then after that you have some code like this:

```
if (!q.empty()) {
  auto element = q.back();
  q.pop();
}
```

in this example two thread going to execute this piece of code check and they will notice queue is not empty after that they will go inside if condition and one of threads first get back element then after that with luck same thread will pop element. after that thread two going to get back element both since thread 1 popped element and now queue is empty then thread 2 back method fail with exception so thread 2 was entered in if condition with condition of queue is not empty then it failed. so this queue is not thread safe

Comment: according to your argumentation no container can be threadsafe, but your point is moot. A container that offers atomic operations (atomic in the the sense of: protected via mutex) can be used threadsafe, a container that does not cannot be used thread safe. Thats what makes a threadsafe container, not whether it can be used wrong

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number my point is that it's okay that you put mutex at start and end of operation and it will make it threadsafe but you should also consider some points it still possible you use it wrong because you think it's threadsafe and you can do any possible combination.

Comment: yes, but in general if a class `Foo` is threadsafe and has methods `A` and `B` then calling `A` is thread safe and calling `B` is threadsafe, but to call `A` and `B` "atomically" the caller has to take additional measures. There is no way `Foo` can help with that unless it also provides a method `AB`

Comment: Re, "...my point is...it still possible you use it wrong." Sure. That's a good point to make. Calling "thread safe" packages/libraries/functions/classes absolutely does *NOT* guarantee that your own code will be thread-safe, but that's not the fault of the 3rd-party code. Code is "Thread safe" if it's guaranteed to behave in predictable ways no matter how many threads concurrently use it. Whether you use those guarantees to prove the thread-safety of your own code or, whether you mis-understand and mis-use them is _your_ choice—your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nice to see you are expanding your skills. If you are using C++ then C++11 onwards has threading in the [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). I suggest you use those features instead.